# How many of these items does the electrician put in?

Tags: electrical, heating, security, venting, coaxial-cable

*Planning for a new construction. For the **interior walls** does the electrician:*
***a.*** put in the orange tube for running future technology wires?
**b.** wire for cat 6 Ethernet cabling for hard wire computer connections?
**c.** wire for coaxial for internet and cable?
**d.** wire for security camera?
**e.** wire for security system (creating your own, not using a security company).
**f.**  wire the electrical portion of the furnace?
**g.** wire for 2 zones  for the heating?
**h.** install the venting for the bath fans?
**i.**  install over stove microwave/vented fan and do the venting?

**Or,** which ones are only handled by HVAC or another sub?   THX YOU

Comment: hire a licensed low voltage contractor for anything 50v or less.  Let the HVAC contractor do the venting.

Comment: Many electricians think they can do *any* wiring, in my experience, most can't. For ethernet especially: if they can't tell you the difference between T568A and B, or between Cat6 and Cat5e, for example, don't hire them. Most recently my company moved into a new office, and the landlord had electricians run new network. They stripped and untwisted the wire back 6". Our actual network guys came in, tested, found the signal was horrible, and had to redo everything. The worst part is this would have connected and said it was gigabit, but actual transfer rate would have been awful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question looks like homework, and this StackExchange is for DIY home improvement, not homework help.  SE does not have a homework-help board, but Yahoo Answers does.

Comment: Some electricians can do the entire list but the cost will be higher than most general contractors.  Other than F & I it looks to be work that any one could do in my state. but I agree with @Harper.

Comment: Sorry Harper, I graduated from University 40 years ago and haven't done homework since my MS.  Trying to understand so I can ask intelligent questions to an electrician. Don't want him to deal with things outside his area.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is primarily opinion based but IMO it's appropriate for the site.

Here is my take: (mine in **bold**)

a. put in the orange tube for running future technology wires? **Not standard procedure, but certainly a job for the electrician at added cost.**

b. wire for cat 6 Ethernet cabling for hard wire computer connections? **Not standard procedure for many, but certainly a job for the electrician at added cost. This is standard for me.**

c. wire for coaxial for internet and cable? **For me this is standard procedure.**

d. wire for security camera? **Not standard procedure, but certainly a job for the electrician at added cost.**

e. wire for security system (creating your own, not using a security company). **Not standard procedure, but certainly a job for the electrician at added cost.**

f. wire the electrical portion of the furnace? **Typically the electrician's job.**

g. wire for 2 zones for the heating? **If you mean the control wiring for me it's a toss up. Both HVAC contractors and electrician will do this.**

h. install the venting for the bath fans? **Typically the electrician, but some will leave it for the GC Or HVAC.**

i. install over stove microwave/vented fan and do the venting? **Typically the circuit and receptacle are the electrician. Installation and venting are GC.**

Answer (score 0):

I've been an electrician for about 5 years and I'm familiar with the most of the work you need done:
**A**. An electrician or a low voltage tech can easily install the required conduit.
**B**, **C**, **D**, **E**. This is a low voltage field, but a knowledgeable electrician is certainly fine.
**F**. This is something I'd recommend an electrician preforming.
**G**. If the electrician is familiar with control wiring that's fine. If not you may need to ask an HVAC tech.
**H**. This falls under the HVAC category, but anyone can install a vent as long as they know what they're doing. 
**I**. Have the electrician do the wiring. Have the HVAC guy to the vent.